# соответствие ООП концепции java

Tags: java, ооп

На примере нахождения факториала хочется узнать насколько я правильно понимаю ООП. Представим факториал как самостоятельную сущность:

```
public class Factorial {
  private double number;
  private double result;

  public void setNumber(double number) {
    this.number = number;
  }
  public double getResult() {
    return calcFactorial(this.number);
  }

  private double calcFactorial(double number){
    this.result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <=number; i++){
      this.result *= i;
    } return this.result;
  }
}
```

Правильно ли скрыть поведение или сделать его доступным другим классам? Тогда получается getResult не нужен.. что-то я совсем запутался во всём этом. Подскажите как правильно?

Comment: геттер getResult() должен возвращать result, а не вычислять что-то. Либо вообще уберите поля result и number, и setNumber, getResult. оставьте один метод calcFactorial и сделайте его публичным. зачем хранить состояния, если этот класс утилитаный? и назовите его просто calc, иначе вызывать Вы будете factorial.calcFactorial(5)

Comment: Вообще говоря, классами описывают то, что хранит состояние, а факториал - это функция, которая состояния не имеет, так что пример не очень. Нормальным примером был бы, например, монстр с хитпоинтами в private поле, при изменении которых в сеттере меняется его полоска здоровья.

Comment: хорошо. я убрал поля и геты/сеты. оставил паблик метод calc. но стоит ли тогда городить класс или есть смысл сделать метод calc в том классе в котормо нужно производить вычисление. или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Если уже подходить с такой сторны, то городить целый класс для факториала неправильно. Делайте уже тогда класс Math, а в нем реализацию паблик методов factorial(n), sum(m,n) и т.д. Если Вам нужна реализация своего факториала(любого другого метода) для каких-то операций с данными - делаете приватный метод и вызвыаете его внутри класса, в котором произодятся манипуляции,  из других методов

Comment: я бы вообще задал вопрос, чему равен факториал 1.5 например) И да, это не 1. Не стоит врать сигнатурами.... Ну и да, если уже так надо - передавайте number в конструктор и вычисляйте там же, а то странно выглядит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> но стоит ли тогда городить класс или есть смысл сделать метод calc в том классе, в котором нужно производить вычисление..

Классы, конечно же, должны соответствовать концепциям ООП, однако не совсем верно говорить о корректности класса, отрываясь от контекста его использования.

Возьмём этот же пример с факториалом и рассмотрим два случая:

1. Студенту нужно выполнить лабораторную работу (написать программу, выполняющую какие-то вычисления с факториалами из комбинаторики, например, перестановки или сочетания).
2. Работнику фирмы нужно разработать калькулятор, который "следит" за пользователем, ведёт лог его действий, поддерживает историю операций и их отмену.

В первом случае, как сказал *Prahvessor* в комментариях, проще и логичнее создать общий класс (аля `Math`) и наполнить его нужными, возможно статичными, методами.

Во втором случае имеет смысл применить паттерн [Команда](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/command) и сделать отдельный класс факториала и других операций. Будет куча классов, где каждый класс реализует свою операцию и сохраняет свое предыдущее состояние. Программа станет ощутимо более сложная, зато это облегчит реализацию логирования/отмены операций и сделает программу более устойчивой к изменениям. Но эта сложность была бы совершенно избыточна в первом случае.

**В итоге**, если пример с факториалом выдуман либо взят из какой-то простой программы, то скорее всего отдельный класс факториала избыточен. Если же **программа достаточно большая** и есть **определенные требования предметной области**, то **возможно** есть смысл задуматься о внедрении такого класса.

Comment: т.е. в зависимости от ситуации мы можем некую сущность опредилить либо как объект либо - метод. а значит в к.г.м добжны быть связи отвечающие за логику данного выбора..

Comment: либо как совокупность объектов.. зависит, на каком уровне абстракции нужно работать с предметной областью. Например, автомобиль. Это может быть один класс, в простейшем варианте имеющий скорость и реализующий метод `move()`. А может быть целый набор классов для тюнинга (двигатель, подвеска, шины, привет из *Need For Speed*), которые могут быть заменены в процессе работы программы и которые влияют на макс. скорость, сцепление с дорогой, управляемость и т.п.  Однако, такое разделение будет избыточно, если нужно двигать иконку автомобиля по экрану с постоянной скоростью.

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть одна нелогичность в цикле. В данном случае нужно итерацию начинать не с 1 а с 2. так как 1*1 не рационально хотя бы с точки зрения скорости выполнения программы.
И в методе calcFactorial(double number) "this" тоже лишний, также как и "this" в return.

**А так вот:**
Ключевые черты ООП:

***Первая*** — инкапсуляция — это определение классов — пользовательских типов данных, объединяющих своё содержимое в единый тип и реализующих некоторые операции или методы над ним. Классы обычно являются основой модульности, инкапсуляции и абстракции данных в языках ООП.

***Вторая*** ключевая черта, — наследование — способ определения нового типа, когда новый тип наследует элементы (свойства и методы) существующего, модифицируя или расширяя их. Это способствует выражению специализации и генерализации.

***Третья*** черта, известная как полиморфизм, позволяет единообразно ссылаться на объекты различных классов (обычно внутри некоторой иерархии). Это делает классы ещё удобнее и облегчает расширение и поддержку программ, основанных на них.

Comment: почему this лишний?

Comment: @Alexey потому что внутри класса к полям класса можно обращаться по имени поля напрямую. this в таких случаях используется для того, чтобы разделить поля класса и локальные переменные методов с одинаковыми именами, в остальных случаях this принято опускать, хотя и его указание не является ошибкой.